# Displaying unicode character U+2661 ("White Heart Suit") in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, unicode, symbols

I can't get this character: ♡ to display properly in Windows Explorer, it instead shows up as a symbol of three lines, similar to this ☰.

The strangest thing is that if i use the heart symbol beside another unusual symbol, such as one of these: ♞♣♢♦♨♫, it will display correctly as a heart; yet if I delete the symbol which is next to the heart it will revert to the 3 lines symbol. All of these other symbols display correctly when used alone.

Does anybody else have this problem?

Is it possible that Windows has 2 different characters listed for U+2661?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What font are you using? The character is displaying just fine in my webbrowser on Win7.

Comment: Hi, Webrowser has no problem displaying the font whatsoever; as a quick test to see if you have the same problem try creating a new txt file, copy the heart character and rename the txt file to the heart character

Comment: Interesting, it behaves as you described in Windows Explorer. I wonder if it switches fonts once it detects a character that can't be displayed in the current font, but thinks it can display the heart.

Comment: Interesting idea. I've been testing with a few different symbols and the heart is the only one with which I can reproduce this behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Sans Serif has that three-bar symbol at U+2661, while correct Unicode fonts have the heart there. Assuming you're not using Microsoft Sans Serif in the first place, Windows is most likely defaulting to Microsoft Sans Serif when you use U+2661 because that character doesn't exist in whatever font you *are* using. However, when you use another character nearby in the Unicode table, which Microsoft Sans Serif lacks for whatever reason, the system is switching to yet another font.

Comment: Indeed weird, but you're right about Microsoft Sans Serif having this character there. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/microsoft_sans_serif/grid.htm boldly claims *nothing* is at that location, but even [on a Mac I get that symbol](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0x4Y3.png) in Microsoft Sans Serif, so it's surely in the font. Nice find!

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that on Win 7, if you try to rename a file to ♡, then indeed the symbol is displayed like ☰. Win 7 uses Segoe UI in Windows Explorer, and Segoe UI lacks ♡, so this appears to be some odd font substitution. But none of the fonts in my system contains such a glyph for ♡.

When I test with your test string ♞♣♢♦♨♫ with ♡ inserted, namely ♞♣♢♡♦♨♫, then file rename shows only ♣ and ♦ property, others are substituted by small rectangles, the common way of indicating lack of glyphs. This is really the expected behavior. But if I delete the rectangle corresponding to ♢, then the next rectangle (for ♡) changes to ☰.

So it’s fairly odd, but the explanation seems to be that under some conditions, when using Segoe UI, Win 7 shows “☰” for “♡”, and this should be taken just as a strange symbol, different from the common rectangle, for “cannot show this character in the current font.”

Answer (score -1):

The character encoding has to be consistent and unicode derived, like UTF-8, UCS-2 any localized encoding will 'break your heart'. This makes cool characters fall over constantly.

As stated above, the font has to support the character,

Fileformat has a tool called 'local font list' ... it will show you which font contains your heart.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2661/browsertest.htm

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question.